# How does Overkill work in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Some of the new Hearthstone cards have an "Overkill" bonus.

How does Overkill work, and are there any particular strategies that help one to take advantage of it?

Answer (score 11):

From the [Hearthstone wiki](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Overkill) (emphasis added):

> Overkill is an ability that activates whenever the card with the keyword deals damage to a character exceeding its current Health **during your turn**.

It was introduced in the December 4, 2018 expansion.

As for strategies, I believe that that is a very broad question, but a player could use it to gain tempo by slightly Overkilling a minion to summon another, such as using the 5 mana [Baited Arrow](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Baited_Arrow) to kill another minion with 2 or less health remaining, to summon a 5/5 Devilsaur at the same time.

[Ironhide Direhorn](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ironhide_Direhorn) looks like another good card if it could survive a turn/attack immediately, perhaps when combo'd with Rush to let it Overkill a minion and summon a 5/5 Ironhide Runt.

Personally, I think [Totemic Smash](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Totemic_Smash) looks like it will give the best value for a Turn 1 play if the opponent plays a card with 1 HP; or it could also be used to remove another minion if you lack 1 HP to kill it with your other minions on board, in order to Overkill by 1 HP.

Comment: This is great!  I'll upvote tonight. I MAY have hit my upvote limit catching up with good posts I'd missed in my questing for hats, but I'll circle back as soon as they reset - thanks!

Comment: In general, it seems there are few basic ways this is to be utilised. 1. impede momentum of cheap decks. 2. buff a card to reach its overkill effect 3. debuff an enemy monster to reach your own overkill 4. setup for overkill on next turn by doing damage to a minion this turn. Strategies can build up from there depending on the exact overkill effects chosen.